# cgroups: can specific core of cpu be limited for time quota?

Tags: cgroups

As far as I've read man pages, it is not possible to limit specific core to say 50% while limiting the whole CPU to 25%. Only options are mimiting set of cores and total processor time quotas. Combining cotrollers with AND only (AFAIK no OR for limits in cgroups) I don't see the way.

But maybe there is some trick? Potential tools are not limited to `cgroups`.